# CodeIgniter Select Option Only Passing First Value To PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fix a bug in a code written in codeigniter. I have a selector where I need to select different options, but on selecting different option, on submit the value is taken as first option only.

As shown in the below pic, even if I select '2nd Stanard', '3rd Standard' etc, it always auto selects '1st Standard'.

[image]
Like this below no matter what option I select, it always shows '1st Standard' only.

[image]

Below is the corresponding php code:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'admin/section/', array('class' => 'form m-b'));?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="gi" for=""><?php echo get_phrase('class');?>:</label>
                <select class="form-control" onchange="submit();" name="class_id">
                <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select');?></option>
                <?php $cl = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
                 foreach($cl as $row):
                ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>" <?php if($class == $row['class_id']) echo 'selected';?>><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
              <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
```

How to fix this issue?

EDIT:
The below code works in another page for different options:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'admin/students/', array('class' => 'form m-b'));?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="gi" for=""><?php echo get_phrase('class');?>:</label>
                <select class="form-control" onchange="submit();" name="class_id">
                <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select');?></option>
                <?php $cl = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
                 foreach($cl as $row):
                ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>" <?php if($id == $row['class_id']) echo 'selected';?>><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
              <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: `<select multiple name="class_id[]"`

Comment: `onchange = submit()` How is the form submitted? Ajax? It looks like it could be reloading the page, which is resetting the index of your select to the first one if the form is actually being submitted.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I don't want to select multiple options, I need the selected option to be shown.

Comment: as @Kisaragi says, this could be js issue, maybe the submit function is not available in your layout

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let me know where got the data of $class or where you had defined.
Below code, I have tried and it works fine.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php/Welcome/fetchDataFromTable');?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="submit();" name="select_dropdown">
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                        <?php 
                            $class = '';
                            $cl = array(
                                '1' => '1st Standard',
                                '2' => '2nd Standard',
                                '3' => '3rd Standard',
                                '4' => '4th Standard',
                                '5' => '5th Standard',
                            );
                            foreach($cl as $k => $v){
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>" <?php if($class == $k) echo 'selected'; ?> >
                                    <?php echo $v; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php 
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```